# SSRS SUBSCRIPTION: Failure sending mail: Unknown ErrorMail will not be resent

Tags: ssrs-2012

I want to send email directly to users by using subscription but in subsciption status shows the error 
Failure sending mail: Unknown ErrorMail will not be resent.

Comment: Go to SSRS log directly for get more information and post it to help you. In report manager suscriptions there are general error messages. Default path is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.xxxx\Reporting Services\LogFiles

Comment: @alejandrozuleta it was solved automatcally , I dont know what was the actual problem ?

Comment: Nice! Maybe a transitory network issue